# How to link props in react-hook-form to the field and fieldState fields in the render of the reused component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm creating a "CustomInputController" component that accepts "InputCommonProps" and "UseControllerProps" and returns a "Controller" with "InputCommon" as a pure component. Props `InputCommonProps` with `field` and `fieldState` are not bound to `render` inside `Controller`.
I can't decide how to tie them.

This is the component itself:

```
import { InputCommon, InputCommonProps } from '@some';

type ICustomInputProps = Omit<InputCommonProps, 'error' | 'size'>;
type ICustomControllerProps = Omit<UseControllerProps, 'render'>;

export function CustomInputController({
  controllerProps,
  inputProps,
}: {
  controllerProps: ICustomControllerProps;
  inputProps: ICustomInputProps;
}) {
  return (
    <Controller
      {...controllerProps}
      // inputProps with the field field are connected to field in the Controller's render
       // similar to fieldState
      render={({ field, fieldState }) => (
        <InputCommon {...inputProps} error={fieldState.error?.message} size={InputCommon.sizes.Large} />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

The example where I use it should work as commented code:

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

import { composeValidators } from '@some';
// import { InputCommon } from '@some';
import { Textarea } from '@some';

import { FormKey } from '#constants/InstanceFormFields';
import { useValidators } from '#hooks/useValidators';
import { CustomInputController } from '#shared/Custom/CustomInputController';
import { translations } from '#utils/i18n';

import { FIELD_MAX_LENGTH } from '../constants';

export function FieldsCommon() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  const { required, latinNumbersDashesUnderscores, latinCyrillicNumbersDashesUnderscores, stringMaxLength } =
    useValidators();

  return (
    <>
      <CustomInputController
        controllerProps={{
          name: FormKey.Name,
          rules: {
            validate: composeValidators(
              required,
              latinNumbersDashesUnderscores,
              stringMaxLength(FIELD_MAX_LENGTH[FormKey.Name]),
            ),
          },
        }}
        inputProps={{
          // all fields are not linked to the field in the Controller's render
          // similar to fieldState 
          value: field.value,
          onChange: field.onChange,
          label: t(translations.InstanceEditor.fields.name.label),
          placeholder: t(translations.InstanceEditor.fields.name.placeholder),
          maxLength: FIELD_MAX_LENGTH[FormKey.Name],
        }}
      />
      {/* <Controller
        name={FormKey.Name}
        rules={{
          validate: composeValidators(
            required,
            latinNumbersDashesUnderscores,
            stringMaxLength(FIELD_MAX_LENGTH[FormKey.Name]),
          ),
        }}
        render={({ field, fieldState }) => (
          <InputCommon
            value={field.value}
            onChange={field.onChange}
            label={t(translations.InstanceEditor.fields.name.label)}
            placeholder={t(translations.InstanceEditor.fields.name.placeholder)}
            error={fieldState.error?.message}
            size={InputCommon.sizes.Large}
            maxLength={FIELD_MAX_LENGTH[FormKey.Name]}
          />
        )}
      /> */}
    </>
  );
}
```